# Show "Heat Map" image with alpha values - Matplotlib / Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgba, colorbar, imshow

I'm trying to plot some data to analyze them.

My data is defined as below:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, rows=200, cols=300):
        """
        The Data constructor
        """
        # The data grid
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        # The 2D data structure
        self.data = numpy.zeros((rows, cols), float)
```

At first, I had this method:

```
  def generate_data_heat_map(data, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, plot_title, file_path):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(plot_title)
    fig = plt.imshow(data.data, extent=[0, data.cols, data.rows, 0])
    plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis_label)
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

This gives me something as a heat map image (second figure), 'cause I'm passing to it an MxN [luminance (grayscale, float array only)]. And don't know why this doesn't generate a grayscale image, but so far I didn't worry about it 'cause that is the result I wanted.

After some more calculation, I had this method to visualize my data, using the **data_property** as RGB and **data_uncertaity** as alpha:

```
def generate_data_uncertainty_heat_map(data_property, data_uncertainty, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, plot_title, file_path):
    plt.figure()
    uncertainty = numpy.zeros((data_property.rows, data_property.cols, 4))
    uncertainty[..., :3] = data_property.data[..., numpy.newaxis]
    uncertainty[..., 3] = data_uncertainty.data
    plt.title(plot_title)
    fig = plt.imshow(uncertainty.data, extent=[0, data_property.cols, data_property.rows, 0])
    plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis_label)
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

But, of course, this give me a grayscale image with alpha values, since I am repeating the same values for R, G and B. But what I really would like to have was the first method result (colored) with some alpha values calculated as uncertainty about the data.

[image]

I've noticed that my color bar has nothing about my data too (it's in RGB, I can't use it to analyze my data)

I don't know how to achieve the result that I want, which is to a have a "heat map" plot with merged the alpha values defined with my **uncertainty_data** and a color bar representing this uncertainty. Like merging this two images above:

This as my color:
[image: Figure 2]

This as my alpha:
[image]

With the conversion presented by @BlazBratanic, I guess I can see a little bit of color (not sure about it), but its far of what I was expecting.

[image]

All my values is between 0.0 and 1.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you now something about it, @ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Matplotlib cm module](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) to map your grayscale to color values. If i remember correctly "jet" is the default colormap. So you would do something like:

```
uncertainty = plt.cm.jet(data_property.data)
uncertainty[..., 3] = data_uncertainty.data
```

Comment: Nothing but my test data. (:

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, and with my current version of matplotlib (3.7.1), I can just use the alpha keyword which accepts 2D arrays, so something like

```
plt.imshow(data_array, ... ,alpha = alpha_array)
```

A MWE would be

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mat = numpy.zeros((150,150))
mat[:,3] = 1
mat[:,45] = 1 #two vertical lines

counts = numpy.tile(numpy.array(list(range(1,151))).reshape(-1,1),[1,150])
counts = counts/numpy.max(counts) # alpha that increases linearly

plt.imshow(mat, cmap = 'binary', alpha = counts)
plt.show()
```